# python urlib AttributeError: 'HTTPResponse' object has no attribute 'readall'

Tags: python

I am following a tutorial on tkinter with some urlib in it and get this error message.

```
AttributeError: 'HTTPResponse' object has no attribute 'readall'
```

here is the code:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib import style
import urllib
import json
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


LARGE_FONT= ("Verdana", 12)
style.use("ggplot")

f = Figure(figsize=(5,3), dpi=100)
a = f.add_subplot(111)


def animate(i):
    dataLink = 'https://btc-e.com/api/3/trades/btc_usd?limit=2000'
    data = urllib.request.urlopen(dataLink)
    data = data.readall().decode("utf-8")
    data = json.loads(data)
```

here is the complete trace back

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1550, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_tkagg.py", line 280, in resize
    self.show()
  File "C:\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_tkagg.py", line 351, in draw
    FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)
  File "C:\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 464, in draw
    self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
  File "C:\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 63, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 1150, in draw
    self.canvas.draw_event(renderer)
  File "C:\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 1815, in draw_event
    self.callbacks.process(s, event)
  File "C:\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook.py", line 549, in process
    proxy(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook.py", line 416, in __call__
    return mtd(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 831, in _start
    self._init_draw()
  File "C:\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 1490, in _init_draw
    self._draw_frame(next(self.new_frame_seq()))
  File "C:\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 1512, in _draw_frame
    self._drawn_artists = self._func(framedata, *self._args)
  File "C:\Programs\Python\Python35\tkinter\TutorialTwo.py", line 28, in animate
    data = data.readall().decode("utf-8")
AttributeError: 'HTTPResponse' object has no attribute 'readall'
```

Comment: Could you post the code as well?

Comment: Can you just `read()` that thing? Without arguments, `read()` will try to read to the end. There's no `readall` method on `httplib.HTTPResponse`, as the trace indicated.  Your tutorial is simply wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

HttpResponse has no attribute `readall`.

```
>>> dir(data)
['__abstractmethods__', '__class__', '__del__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__enter__', '__eq__',
 '__exit__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__',
 '__iter__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__next__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__',
 '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '_abc_cache', '_abc_negative_cache',
 '_abc_negative_cache_version', '_abc_registry', '_checkClosed', '_checkReadable', '_checkSeekable', '_checkWritable',
 '_check_close', '_close_conn', '_get_chunk_left', '_method', '_peek_chunked', '_read1_chunked',
 '_read_and_discard_trailer', '_read_next_chunk_size', '_read_status', '_readall_chunked', '_readinto_chunked',
 '_safe_read', '_safe_readinto', 'begin', 'chunk_left', 'chunked', 'close', 'closed', 'code', 'debuglevel', 'detach',
 'fileno', 'flush', 'fp', 'getcode', 'getheader', 'getheaders', 'geturl', 'headers', 'info', 'isatty', 'isclosed',
 'length', 'msg', 'peek', 'read', 'read1', 'readable', 'readinto', 'readinto1', 'readline', 'readlines', 'reason',
 'seek', 'seekable', 'status', 'tell', 'truncate', 'url', 'version', 'will_close', 'writable', 'write', 'writelines']
>>> type(data)
< class 'http.client.HTTPResponse'>
```

try use `read` or `readline`

```
data = data.readline().decode("utf-8")
```

Comment: It might be worth to note that ``readall`` used to be part of ``HTTPResponse``, but has been removed in python 3.5.